# Which episode of Floogals is this scene from?

Tags: episode-identification, floogals

Which episode of Floogals is this from?
[image]

[image]

It appears in the [start sequence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHQNr1nTLX0) and has been used by the official Floogals [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=1793092660711546) and [Twitter](https://twitter.com/WeAreFloogals/status/996646431346720769) feeds

Comment: Valorum
 No, it's an excerpts from all episodes  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHQNr1nTLX0

Comment: Hmm. The most likely candidate looks like the Season 1 episode "Project Picnic" but I can't find an episode to view

Comment: Unfortunately, I watched this episode, not this one

Comment: Did you watch the full episode or the 3 minute 'short' version?

Comment: watch the full episode

Comment: Someone else asking [here](https://twitter.com/theburrow1/status/1242949924133765120)

Comment: Please stop making pointless edits (e.g. just adding/removing whitespace) to your post. Only edit your post if you're making some *improvement* such as correcting grammar or adding more information.